# virsh: error loading shared libraries: libyajl.so.2 is missing

Tags: kvm-virtualization, rhel7

I just tried to setup some KVMs on RHEL7. My procedure was:

```
yum install qemu-kvm qemu-img
yum install virt-install libvirt libvirt-client libvirt-client
```

The I tried out

virsh list --all

to checkout if everything is OK. But I got the following error code:

```
virsh: error while loading shared libraries: libyajl.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Then I looked after a rpm-package to fix it on: http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/3/srodzaj/1/search/libyajl.so.2%28%29%2864bit%29

But there is no version for RHEL 7 in the list.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

https://www.redhat.com/archives/libvirt-users/2014-July/msg00001.html

As recommendet I tried out:

```
yum install yajl-devel
```

That solved my issue.